# How to retain foreign key references when updating item with jpa

Tags: java, json, jpa, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot rest service to save users and its addresses like this:

```
@Entity
class User {
    @Id
    String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    List<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity
class Address {
    @Id(autogenerated...)
    int id;
    String street;
    @ManyToOne
    User user; 
}

@RestController
class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(method = ...PUT, value = ...)
    public void update(@PathVariable User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

Suppose there is user Dave with two addresses ("id=1, street=Street 1"; "id=2, street=Street 2") already in database. Now I am sending this POST request to service in order to update just one of Dave's addresses:

```
{
    "name": "Dave",
    "address": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "street": "Street 3"           // ONLY THIS FIELD UPDATED
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "street": "Street 2"
      }
    ]
}
```

Because of **cascade** attribute in @OneToMany annotation present in User Entity class those addresses should be updated in database - and they are. The problem for me is that after that `user_id` columns of these addresses are **NULL** now, i.e. addresses lost its reference to user. Why is that happening and how to solve that?

**EDIT QUESTION:** What is the easiest way to implement (via JPA) that when *updating User in the same time User's addresses are updated too?*